# Is Chromium in 18.04 really preventing me from following softlinks outside of my home folder?

Tags: permissions, chromium, symbolic-link

I have an old drive where I put files which I do not care much about. I mounted it as `/mnt/crap` (well chosen name!).

There I create a directory with my name: `/mnt/crap/alexis`.

I create a link to that folder from my home directory:

```
/home/alexis/crap -> /mnt/crap/alexis
```

I can go there with Nautilus, add files, etc. since I setup the proper permissions on that `alexis` directory it all works as expected.

However, when I go in Chromium and I click on the `crap` folder, it tells me:

> Permissions denied.

and it shows nothing. If I go to `/`, the try to click on `mnt`, same error.

Is there a way to give chromium permission to access files outside of my home folder?

Comment: You haven't mentioned what release; my duplicate link assumes 19.10 and won't apply to other releases.  If you're talking about 19.10 you need to enable Chromium:removable-media to enable access to /mnt, /media..  (see aforementioned duplicate link)

Comment: @guiverc, same resolution, I could go in the Ubuntu Software window, find Chromium and click Permissions. Now it works (at least for `/mnt` which is enough for me.)